# Mobile chat offset incorrect when rotating device while keyboard is shown

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-safari

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open mobile chat
2. Tap the message text field to pull up the keyboard.
3. Rotate the device.
4. Rotate the device back.

Expected behavior:
The chat view should be visible above the keyboard.

Actual behavior:
The page does not update to reflect the new keyboard size, and the input text field and other chat messages are blocked by the keyboard.

> [image: Mobile Web]

Also tagging this with [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) since the issue appears with the `SFSafariViewController` as well.

> [image: SFSafariViewController]

Expected result:

> [image: Expected Chat Offset]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Comment: Don't think the iOS tag is relevant since it's essentially opening in mobile safari and the behaviour isn't any different

Comment: Yeah, I'm dropping [tag:ios-app] because the behavior is identical in Safari proper.  The bug is in the mobile chat.